# Error jwt must not be accepted before

Tags: c#, jwt, tokens

Estoy haciendo pruebas para generar Token y ahorita que estoy validandolo tengo este problema "jwt must not be accepted before", estuve haciendo pruebas poniendo

```
tokenHandler.SetDefaultTimesOnTokenCreation = false
```

Pero aun asi tengo ese error cuando hago pruebas, adjunto la forma en como estoy haciendo la generacion de mi TOKEN, estuve investigando que es por el "nbf" hay alguna forma de excluir o removerlo?

```
var llave = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ");
var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
var iat = (DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds;
var exp = (DateTime.Now.AddHours(24).ToUniversalTime().Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds;
   
var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor          
{
    Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
    {
        new Claim("RFC", IdCompany),
        new Claim("user", user),
        new Claim("macAdress", macAdress),
        new Claim("iat", iat.ToString()),
        new Claim("exp", exp.ToString()),

    }),
    Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(24),
    SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(llave), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
};
var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
string userToken = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
return userToken;
```

Comment: hola ya probaste usando asincronia? [vease](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48839498/is-awaiting-methods-from-synchronous-sources-with-await-task-run-good-prac)

Comment: no pero no tendria que cambiar la forma en como hago el metodo?